# Autocomplete stops working Accord.Math, Visual Studio 2019, C#

Tags: c#, autocomplete, visual-studio-2019, accord.net

After installing the latest VS patch, autocomplete stopped working. It consistently gets a thread burning CPU (i9-9880H) for 57 seconds, after which it offers the autocomplete list.

I found a consistent way of turning this delay on and off; importing the NuGet package "Accord.Math". Note that for example MathNet.Numerics has not the same problem as I've tried to only remove this package instead - didn't help.

It happens on all variables, even in files where Accord.Math is not imported. Here is an example of a double:

[image: Accord.Math autocomplete example]

Other things I've tried which didn't work:

- Repairing VS
- Reinstalling VS
- Installing the previous patch of VS 2019
- Updating all NuGet packages to latest version
- Installing Accord.Math on other projects of the solution instead

I haven't installed any plugin (i.e. ReSharper), and it's Visual Studio Professional 2019, Version 16.6.2

How could I fix the lag while keeping Accord.Math?

Is there a way to disable all the extension methods in a specific library from taking part in the autocomplete?

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem. A temporary way to get rid of the "cpu burning" is to delete the package "Accord.Math.3.8.0" with the file explorer before starting vs2019. But after each built the package will be reloaded and then the problem occurs again.

I would be highly interested in a stable solution too.

Comment: me too. Same problem